# DDD: aggregate that contains references to other aggregate root but the aggregate root has specific functionality inside the first

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate, let's call it `Party`. For a party, I can have many `People` which is an aggregate as well as they can exist on their own without the `Party`. But specifically for the `Party` , I want to keep track of how much `Food` was eaten by each person.

How can I model this? The Food cannot exist without the `People` at the `Party`  so I don't consider this a separate aggregate. `Food` has items inside it.

I have modelled `Party` as follows:

```
{
    partyId: number
    people: [
        {
            peopleId: number
            food: {
             sausages: 2
             burgers: 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this the correct way to model the data?

If I want to get the details for one person at a `Party`, how would I model the method? Is it a case of having a repository method to get a party by its id and then filtering the `People` array by the id of the person I want?

I have modelled the data but it doesn't feel quite right to me.

**Edit:**

Thanks to one of the answers, I have changed the `Party aggregate` to be:

```
{
    id: number
    participants: [
        {
            personId: number
            food: {
             kind: string
             quantity: number
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `People` aggregate has been renamed `Person`:

```
{
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

This better communicates the relationship and I think is easier to understand.

Comment: As long as you reference the other aggregate with its Id, it's generally fine. Avoid nesting whole aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that:

- the `people` member seems to be a list of "decorated" `peopleId` references and not a list of people entities (which would require to duplicate people participating to several parties)
- the `food` sub-member member is a collection of value objects (i.e. having no identity and solely identified by the kind of food and the quantities consumed in the enclosing party)

this design is perfectly fine and compliant with DDD principles.

In fact, the `people` member implements a many to many association between party and people.  I'd recommend to rename it `Participants`, to avoid the ambiguity with `People` entities.  And the food appears to implement an association class:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.

I am a touch confused about your diagram, if `Participants` should replace `People` why are they both on the diagram?

If I am correct that `Participants` should replace `People`, is it not a one to-many relationship, as it's many people at one party? And then a one-to-many relationship for `Participants` to PartyFood as it's one participant to many items of food?

Comment: Good question: in the diagram, participant represents a people participating to a party. peope is the people, independently of any party. This what I meant with the first bullet. If in your model, the people (including all atributes, like name address, etc) would be embedded in the party, it would no longer be ddd compliant, as you would include one aggregate into another and aggregates would not have the independence they require.

Comment: I think People is the wrong name in this case. The object seems to represent a single person, not a group of people.

Comment: Thank you @Christophe.

So what about this for `Party`: `{  id: number; participants: [{ id: number; personId: number; food: [ { kind: string } ]  }]  }`

Then I would have a seperate `Person` aggregate, replacing `People`.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea (with quantity:number behind kind  ;-) ) .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to one of the other answers (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/450854/266614), I have changed the `Party aggregate` to be:

```
{
    id: number
    participants: [
        {
            personId: number
            food: {
             kind: string
             quantity: number
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `People` aggregate has been renamed `Person`:

```
{
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

This better communicates the relationship and I think is easier to understand.